# Unable to delete files using ansible shell module

Tags: linux, ansible

I am unable to delete the files using ansible shell module. If I run the command(rm -rf) directly on linux server then it is deleting the files but the same is not working from shell module.

My palybook is not throwing any error and task is shown completed successfully but in actual files are not getting deleted.

```
- hosts: myhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  user: ansible
  vars:
   ansible_become_password: 'lk121'
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
      var_01: /home/guj/bang
   - shell: rm -rf "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/logs/access*log*"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/logs/*log*"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/tmp"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/cache"
     register: del_var_01_files
     delegate_to: guj01_machine
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Not knowing Ansible terribly well, I don't know whether the double quotes in `rm -rf "{{ item }}"` will remain when the command is executed. If so, the globbing patterns would not be expanded by the executing shell (quoted globbing patterns are not expanded). This in turn means that unless the files have those _literal_ names, nothing would be deleted.  There's also a difference in the mount of white space in `{{ item }}` compared to `{{var_01}}`. I'm uncertain whether this is significant.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the Shell module and not the File module with `state: absent`?

Comment: As @DopeGhoti says, `shell` should only be used if you really can't avoid it - which is rare.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `file` module to remove the files, as that's (in part) what it's there for:

```
- hosts: myhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  user: ansible
  vars:
   ansible_become_password: 'this_should_be_in_an_ansible_vault'
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
      var_01: /home/guj/bang
   - file
     with_items:
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/logs/access*log*"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/logs/*log*"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/tmp"
      - "{{var_01}}/servers/*/cache"
     state: absent
     delegate_to: guj01_machine
```